# boolean expression evaluation in C++

Tags: c++, boolean-expression

Say I have this C++ code (it's from a binary tree problem)

```
if(t->left != nullptr && t->left->data != t->data)
```

Isn't it problematic since I try to access possibly a nullpointer's data? Or does it work? because the boolean evaluation happens in a specific order.

Comment: Check out whats is Short-circuit evaluation

Answer (score 0):

If the first condition results to `false`, the second one is not evaluated. So it's completely safe.